# golang domain driven design entities including json attributes in structs

Tags: go, domain-driven-design

I am using DDD to design my go application.  In the entity layer, I will be using `structs` and it looks like this

```
type FruitBasket struct {
    Id      int64  `json:"ref"`
    private string `json:"ttl"`
}
```

Is it ok to include the `json` attributes in this `struct` which forms the entity layer in the `DDD`?  I would prefer not to do it, but not sure.  Is there any other alternative which I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the JSON tags are used to unmarshal requests and marshal responses in HTTP APIs.

Something that gives you more dynamicity is having specific request and response structures like this example, which I took from Mat Ryers post of
[How I write HTTP services after eight years.](https://pace.dev/blog/2018/05/09/how-I-write-http-services-after-eight-years.html)

```
func (s *server) handleSomething() http.HandlerFunc {
    type request struct {
        Name string
    }
    type response struct {
        Greeting string `json:"greeting"`
    }
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note following the go naming conventions I would chance the field name Id to ID.

Also unexported fields are ignored by the encoding/JSON package.